# How to throw error on unsuccessful type assertion in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I'm making function, that fetches API and returns list of objects, but response type can be not matched with the excepted

```
// Very simplified example of what's going on

const response = await fetch("https://test.api.com/Users"); // it returns User[];
const json = response.json();

if (!json.isInType<School[]>()) { // I don't know how to realize function with this behavior
    throw new Error("Types are not matched"); // because User[] is not School[]
};
```

The function should try to parse object to type, and if it's unsuccessful, to return false or throw error

The wanted type is the parameter, so I can't write schema for it

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use validation libraries like [io-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/) or [zod](https://zod.dev/) to validate data types at runtime, my suggestion is zod, Here is [a real example](https://github.com/psparsa/AlphaGallery/blob/main/source/client/src/api/services/get-posts.ts#L106) if you need to check out, or:

```js
import { z, ZodError } from 'zod';

const School = z.object({
  id: z.number(),
  name: z.string(),
  // Add other properties as needed
});

const response = await fetch("https://test.api.com/Users");
const json = await response.json();

try {
  School.array().parse(json);
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof ZodError) {
    throw new Error("Types are not matched");
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that wanted type is the parameter (T)